# Wrapping a TextField in my own reusable component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I have a component that adds a `*` at the beginning of typed in text that looks like this:

```
 export default class MyTextField extends Component {

      constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    };
  }

  static propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    value: PropTypes.string
  }

  addSymbol(newValue, symbol) {
    return newValue.indexOf(symbol) === -1 ? `${symbol}${newValue}` : newValue;
  }

  change(input, newValue) {
    console.log(`I am the parent wit newValue ${newValue}.`);
    this.setState({
      value: this.addSymbol(newValue, '*')
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      onChange, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
      ...other
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <TextField
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.change.bind(this)}
        {...other } >
      </TextField >
    );
  }
}
```

Now I use `MyTextField`in another component like this:

```
 <MyTextField
    style={styleTextFields}
    floatingLabelText='Add text'
    type='text'
  />
```

Now when I start typing everything works great.

If I change the code above and add `value='test'` `prop` on `MyTextField` everything breaks.  It appears its because I added a `prop` to `TextField` which can not be overwritten by `MyTextField` `value={this.state.value}`.

So how can I add `prop` `value` and still add a `*` at the beginning of the typed text?

The other part is if the user adds their own `onChange`, how can I get both `MyTextField` and the component using `MyTextField` `onChange` events to get called?

=======Beginning of Edit 1===============

@Patrick - I have made tweaks based on your comment and the first part is now working.  So I can type in `<TextField />` and I see the changes.

The changes are below:

```
export default class MyTextField extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: props.value ? this.addSymbol(props.value.toString(), '*') : ''
    };
  }

  static propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    value: PropTypes.string
  }

  addSymbol(newValue, symbol) {
    return newValue.indexOf(symbol) === -1 ? `${symbol}${newValue}` : newValue;
  }

  change(input, newValue) {
    console.log(`I am the parent wit newValue ${newValue}.`);
    this.setState({
      value: this.addSymbol(newValue, '*')
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      value, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
      onChange, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
      ...other
  } = this.props;

    return (
      <TextField
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.change.bind(this)}
        {...other } >
      </TextField >
    );
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to make the `onChange` tweak because you are not supposed to modify component state?

I also did try this in the `render()` function which does not work:

```
  addSymbol(newValue, symbol) {
    return newValue.indexOf(symbol) === -1 ? `${symbol}${newValue}` : newValue;
  }

  change(input, newValue) {
    console.log(`I am the parent wit newValue ${newValue}.`);
    this.setState({
      value: this.addSymbol(newValue, '*')
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      value, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
      onChange, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
      ...other
  } = this.props;

    return (
      <TextField
        value={this.addSymbol(this.state.value, '*')}
        {...other } >
      </TextField >
    );
  }
```

Anyway, thank you for your help.

=======Ending of Edit 1===============

=======Beginning of Edit 2===============

I fixed the `onChange` event problem by adding my own event called `onNewValueChange` and calling it in the `onChange`.  Here is the final code:

```
export default class MyTextField extends Component {

      constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: props.value ? this.addSymbol(props.value.toString(), '*') : ''
    };
  }

  static propTypes = {
    onNewValueChange: PropTypes.func,
    value: PropTypes.string
  }

  addSymbol(newValue, symbol) {
    return newValue.indexOf(symbol) === -1 ? `${symbol}${newValue}` : newValue;
  }

  change(input, newValue) {
    const value = value: props.value ? this.addSymbol(props.value.toString(), '*') : '';
    this.setState({
      value: value
    });

    if(this.props.onNewValueChange) {
        this.props.onNewValueChange(value);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      onNewValueChange, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
      ...other
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <TextField
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.change.bind(this)}
        {...other } >
      </TextField >
    );
  }
}
```

Now I use `MyTextField` in another component like this:

```
<MyTextField
    style={styleTextFields}
    floatingLabelText='Add text'
    type='text'
    onNewValueChange={(newValue) => console.log(newValue) }
  />
```

@Patrick thank you for your help getting me in the right direction.

=======Ending of Edit 2===============

Comment: you're trying to pass the same prop twice to the component, why not add a logical check to see if the prop was provided? and if it was, set it as the state in the constructor ? also instead of running your logic "onChange" to add a symbol, why not simply run this logic on each render?

Comment: @Patrick I edited my post based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I think this pattern of omitting props before passing everything else inside a component is confusing, at least for me. Being explicit as possible should always be a priority.

If I understood you correctly, the expected behavior is as follows:

1. You can pass a default text, this text should be prefixed with a * by your component.
2. You can modify the text, but no matter how you modify it, it should always be prefixed with a * - so an empty string should just be *.

I've created this fiddle which hopefully does what you meant : https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/78041/

The key concept is to separate between props and state, a prop is passed only once, and should really be responsible for the initial state of your

Here's the two classes I created :

```
class Input extends React.Component{
  render(){
   return (<input onChange={this.props.onChange} value={this.props.value}/>)
  }
}

class WrappedInput extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
      super();

    let val = props.value || '';
    this.state = {
        value : this.addSymbol(val,'*')
    }
  }

  handleChange(e){
    let newVal = e.target.value;
    this.setState({value:this.addSymbol(newVal,'*')});
  }

  addSymbol(newValue, symbol) {
    return newValue.indexOf(symbol) === -1 ? `${symbol}${newValue}` : newValue;
  }

  render(){
   return (<Input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.value}/>)
  }
}
```

Comment: I want the `Input` object to wrap the string logic so anyone using `input` can have the same functionality.  I also want anyone using `input` to able to subscribe to `onChange` event so they are be alerted about changes.  In m real app(this is a small example of what i'm doing), I have 10 different text boxes needing the same functionality so I want a reusable component in one place instead of copying code.

Comment: I saw you accepted my answer, I hope it pointed you in the right direction